# Stub on an Active LDAP model only works once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ldap

I'm using RSpec to test my RoR App, and am using ActiveLDAP internally. I'm now writing specs for a controller that creates new objects via ActiveLDAP, and so I wrote a few lines like this to dummy the behaviour of creating a record:

```
before(:each) do
  @sample_attributes = {"a" => "b", "c" => "d"}
  @cu = Cloud::User.new
  @cu.stub(:save).and_return false
  @cu.stub(:attributes=).with(@sample_attributes).and_return @sample_attributes
  Cloud::User.stub(:new).and_return @cu
end
```

The purpose of this is to allow to put expectations on the @cu model, in order to ensure that it will have certain commands run against it. Like so:

```
it "should save the new cloud user" do
  @cu.should_receive(:save).and_return false
  post 'create', :cloud_user => @sample_attributes
end

it "should set the attributes of the new cloud user" do
  @cu.should_receive(:attributes=).with(@sample_attributes).and_return @sample_attributes
  post 'create', :cloud_user => @sample_attributes
end
```

Pretty simple, right? Well here's the problem. The first one succeeds, but the second one always throws this error:

```
private method `new' called for #<Class:0x007f8bcad775c8>
```

When it's running this line in the controller:

```
@cloud_user = Cloud::User.new
```

No, that's not a private method. And the EXACT SAME LINE works fine in the first test. Furthermore, it isn't anything intrinsic to the individual test. If I reverse the order of the two tests then the set the attributes test succeeds and the save the user test fails. Basically, it succeeds on whichever one is run first and fails on whichever one is run second.

WHY?

Does anyone have any ideas? I have to think it has something to do with how the stub command works with ActiveLDAP, maybe, but I don't know. It seems SO SIMPLE!